# Question regarding optimal excel function implementation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a question about Excel! I hope that isn't too unconventional for this site...

So I have an Excel table with several thousand rows. It is kind of setup like a db in that the first three of my four columns have numerical values identifying the sequence or order that the content or fourth row contains.

I am running into some possible duplication issues, and I am remembering back to my college days something about there being a function for the type of test I need to do. I need to verify that there are no two rows that have the same values for column 1-3. There should never be a time where all three columns' values match exactly that of another row.

Is VLookUp the function I need? Any excel experts out there that know of a function I could look into? Thanks so much!

Comment: You could use a pivot table to determine if there any duplicates. If there area  lot, working with these en masse would requie a bit more thought though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quick one-off solution I employ for this kind of quest is the following

1. create a single key in one temporary column - say F "**=A2 & B2 & C2 ...**" if combined key - I copy this formula all the way down
2. create a group counter for that single key - say G "**=IF(F2=F1,G1+1,1)**" - I can safely include the header row here because it will move the formula into the false part
3. This formula in G numerates all identical keys from 1 to N and starts by 1 for a new key - I copy this formula all the way down
4. Important: convert G formulae into values (copy / paste special onto itself)
5. sort descending by G and delete/manipulate all rows where counter <> 1 - or use autofilter
6. later on I delete F & G columns

this may sound a bit complicated, but especially in large tables VLOOKUP, COUNTIF's etc can be very time consuming.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could create another column that concatenates the first 3, then do a countif on that. Let's say the concatenation column is D and your data begins in the second row:

```
=countif(D:D,D2)
```

Copy the formula down, then filter on >1.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a countifs function.

assume you add one formula in a ceel in row 4:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A4,B:B,B4,C:C,C4)
```

and copy to formula to the whole column

Then the cells with value 1 is a unique set while those larger than 1 have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check the data once, try the "Remove duplicates" functionality. This can be found in the Data tab -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates. Just unselect all but the first three columns in the dialog and Excel will do the rest.